# Displaying the result of an api on a horizontal scroll bar in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I have successfully made an API call and the result is currently displaying on my WordPress webpage but I want to display the result of this API call in a horizontal scrollbar (that scrolls from left to right) using a short code.

Comment: WRITING IN CAPITALS is often used to represent SHOUTING, so can be considered rude. Other than that, you need to provide a bit more detail about what you're trying to achieve; maybe show some code that you have so far?

Comment: I am sorry about the writing in capital letter. I am querying an API to get some data from there and display on my webpage.

Comment: But I dont just want to display this data plainly on the webpage. I want this data that I haver retrieved from the API call to be displayed on an horizontal scroll with movement.

Comment: Where data comes from has very little to do with how it's displayed. Breaking the problem down is a key skill in programming. So, forget about the API for a moment, and think about how to display a fixed string ("Hello, world" is traditional, but maybe you need something longer to test with.) Then, have a look at the help pages [ask] and [mre] and think about what would help others to help you: explain what you know already, what you already have, and what you want it to look like. Use the [edit] link to update the question, not this comment section.